# How to Use LINE Notify for send images

Tags: python

I have a code send notify to line but this code can't send images from my computer.
Now I can send by url(imageThumbnail,imageFullsize) but I want to send image from my computer.

```
import requests
import urllib.parse
import sys

LINE_ACCESS_TOKEN="LINE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
url = "https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify" 

data = ({
        'message':"Test Image",
        'imageFile':'C://../main@2x.png'
    })
LINE_HEADERS = {"Authorization":"Bearer "+LINE_ACCESS_TOKEN}
session = requests.Session()
r=session.post(url, headers=LINE_HEADERS, data=data)
print(r.text)
```

From code don't have error but output: show text only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, i know image is a file type.

```
file = {'imageFile':open('parth','rb')}
```

and

```
session.post(url, headers=LINE_HEADERS, files=file, data=data)
```

Full code

```
import requests
import urllib.parse
import sys

LINE_ACCESS_TOKEN="LINE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
url = "https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify"
file = {'imageFile':open('Parth','rb')}
data = ({
        'message':'Test Image'
    })
LINE_HEADERS = {"Authorization":"Bearer "+LINE_ACCESS_TOKEN}
session = requests.Session()
r=session.post(url, headers=LINE_HEADERS, files=file, data=data)
print(r.text)
```

Thanks. bot...for -1

Answer (score 0):

In C# it can be written as

```
file = {'imageFile':open('Parth','rb')}
```

Comment: But this question is about Python.

Comment: Also, how is that valid C# code regardless? What does `open()` represent in C#?